# The slash command of the discord bot on python does not appear in the list of slash commands of the server

Tags: python

I have this script that, with the /profile command, gives out a small card, how do I make this command appear in the slash commands of my server

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import requests
import io

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    size = (241, 241)

    image = Image.open("card.png")
    img = image.resize((1100, 500))

    url = str(ctx.author.avatar)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    avatar = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    avatar = avatar.convert("RGBA")
    avatar = avatar.resize((size))

    mask = Image.new("L", (size), 0)
    mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    mask_draw.ellipse((0, 0, size), fill=255)

    avatar_rounded = Image.new("RGBA", (size))
    avatar_rounded.paste(avatar, (0, 0), mask=mask)

    img.paste(avatar_rounded, (430, 47), avatar_rounded)

    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name
    mem = ctx.guild.member_count

    headline = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', size=60)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', size=45)

    idraw.text((180, 310), f'{name}' " Присоеденяется!", font=headline)
    idraw.text((420, 395),"Участник " f'№{mem}', font=undertext, fill=((173,173,173,1)))

    img.save("usercard.png")

    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp="usercard.png"))

bot.run(my token)
```

I tried to use the discord-py-slash-command library, but my script simply did not load it and gave the error that meyan does not have this library

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that you can use `discord-py-slash-command` with it:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import requests
import io
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@slash.slash(name="profile")
async def profile(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    # Rest of your code

bot.run("your_token")
```

Your updated code will be like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import requests
import io
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)  # Initialize the slash commands

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})")

@slash.slash(
    name="profile",
    description="Show your profile",
    guild_ids=[YOUR_GUILD_ID]  # Replace with your guild ID
)
async def profile(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Generating profile...")

    size = (241, 241)

    image = Image.open("card.png")
    img = image.resize((1100, 500))

    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    avatar = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    avatar = avatar.convert("RGBA")
    avatar = avatar.resize(size)

    mask = Image.new("L", size, 0)
    mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    mask_draw.ellipse((0, 0, *size), fill=255)

    avatar_rounded = Image.new("RGBA", size)
    avatar_rounded.paste(avatar, (0, 0), mask=mask)

    img.paste(avatar_rounded, (430, 47), avatar_rounded)

    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name
    mem = ctx.guild.member_count

    headline = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', size=60)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', size=45)

    idraw.text((180, 310), f'{name}' " Присоединяется!", font=headline)
    idraw.text((420, 395), "Участник " f'№{mem}', font=undertext, fill=(173, 173, 173, 1))

    img.save("usercard.png")

    await ctx.send(content="Here is your profile:", file=discord.File("usercard.png"))

bot.run("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
```

Comment: After I inserted your updated script, this error came out:
import discord import detected.  Interactions.py is a completely separate library, and is not compatible with d.py models. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\Downloads\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)  # Initialize the slash commands
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: SlashCommand.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sync_commands'